# Defining only one screen density qualifier?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-density

What happens when I define `dimens.xml` file only under `values-hdpi` directory in addition to the default `values` directory? does the system use it for higher densities as well (`xhdpi, xxhdpi, ..`) or does it use the default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android OS looks in the correct folder for `dimens.xml`, so if you are on an hdpi resolution device, Android OS will first look for a `dimens.xml` file in the `values-hdpi`, if it couldn't found it, it will go straight for the default `dimens.xml` file in the default `values` folder. If it was also not found, the system will look for the most relevant one.